# Android webview fullscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have a layout where I need to show a webview on part of the screen. I've set the layout up and in the Graphical Layout in Eclipse, it does look as I want to, like this (logo and heading blacked out):

[image: Layout as shown in the Graphical Layout]

However when I open this layout in the simulator or on a Phone it shows the WebView as a full screen. How do I make a layout like this? Any help is much appreciated!

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Theme.KB_default"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header_background_shape" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heading"
            style="@style/Theme.KB_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name" >
        </TextView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPadlock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/global_secure_connection"
            android:src="@drawable/padlock" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="@color/black" >
    </View>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.41"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/global_logo"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_transparrent_notext" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I seem to be the stupidist guy alive. My layout worked but I forgot to add " setContentView(xml.file);" so it never loaded the XML... Stupid

Answer (score 0):

make one of table block as webview

check this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

You can also check this example by using dialog

http://www.41post.com/4673/programming/android-creating-a-webview-dialog

Comment: that appears to cause the same issue (table)